# Is there any kind of help to protect my question form other peson who edit or delete my question?

Tags: discussion, help-center

I thought this is best forum.
Today I asked a question in photo.stackexchange .

I got my answer from perfect person.
 Then mattdm `https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/1943/mattdm` came told me my question is not clear . I told him my question is already answered. then he found near similar question (not similar). told me ur question is duplicate.
I told him my question is not clear to you but u can find my question duplicate n also told him I will ask to help forum about you. Then I found question is lock as a merged duplicate question.details of the question also gone.
almost all comment deleted . this is  shock able . how can I contact to admin or moderator of this forum

[Memory card recovery software?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48610/memory-card-recovery-software)

Comment: Seriously though, Jemes, we can't see your original question any more, but was it really that *different* from the question it was merged into? What made it different?

Comment: @Pekka웃 that was likely a logged out merge redirect.  If you are logged in, you should be able to chase it to http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48610/ - but otherwise, the entirety of the text of the question is: "Is there any software recover files without format the memory card when any memory card is in raw format (showing dialog box format your drive) ?" http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/2288/ is also relevant.

Comment: @Pekka웃 - It's not, it's a duplicate.

Comment: yes MichaelT you are right

Comment: @JemesBond SoftwareRecs is a very special case currently. They're a *very* new site that just recently got opened to their public and they are *very* afraid of getting overrun with questions that aren't that great of a quality so they moderate *very* actively.  Make sure you read [this post](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/) on Softwarerec meta and consider how to ask a question there - it *can* be done and you likely have a good question for that site *if* you include enough information in the question there.

Comment: Would editing this question for style be really bad form at this point? :-)

Comment: "ur", "u", and "n" are not English words.  Your English writing is very poor, to the level that you should have someone else write questions for you.  This isn't your fault, but we still have to read the mess regardless.  Those for whom English is not a first language do get some slack here, but there is a limit.  You are at best right at that limit in my opinion.  It's not everyone's right to post here, regardless of how well they know English.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Stack Exchange group of site is a community moderated and *edited* collection of sites. The community is attempting to build a base of knowledge for other people to use and learn from and folks like Matt are attempting to make that possible by helping to make questions and answers more clear for other people visiting the site. It's not just *you* that we're providing an answer to when you ask a a question, it's also for other people that have similar questions or issues.

So, I do think the question, which wasn't very clear, is a duplicate, the comments were getting rude, and the answer is still a valuable one for others. It is advisable to read the help topics on the site, they do cover these topics extensively.

Comment: MichaelT providing a link you can see. If it is not clear how they answered.If don't know the answer leave it for other. one man can know anything but some here behave like they know everything . I dont why they do it for point or somethings else.

Comment: @JemesBond the diamond after Joanne's name indicates that she is a moderator on the site and can see *much* more than I can.

Comment: yes I can see it  MichaelT

Comment: JoanneC n MichaelT
I asked same question in  softwarerecs.stackexchange because I thought that this not photographic question . this is software base question. I wanted to delete my question but did not(my mistake). I was really in bad mood after crashing 64GB memory card crash over 3000 NEF (raw photo) deleted .now successfully recovered 1647 files for this forum.Thanks to this forum . Sorry for my rude comments.

Comment: @JemesBond - It's okay. It's worth remembering that we're volunteers here that want to help and, if you stick around and participate, that may well be true of you too. That's the point after all.

Comment: Thank you so much Joanne. I can realize now how much valuable this forum for us. and one thing I should remember that I'm asking for help not demanding so I must be polite.

Comment: @JemesBond - having been through a number of near misses on file losses, I empathize completely with the stress factor.

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: I am not an active participant on Photo.SE (I came here from Meta.SO where this question was asked) so may be a bit off from what the community here expects. I'm also not a mod and so can't see the comments that were on the question and what was deleted apart from what was moved.

From [Memory card recovery software?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/48610/memory-card-recovery-software) the text of the question is:

> Is there any software recover files without format the memory card when any memory card is in raw format (showing dialog box format your drive) ?

This is the same question as [How can I recover photo files from a memory card with a corrupt filesystem?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3323/how-can-i-recover-photo-files-from-a-memory-card-with-a-corrupt-filesystem) which the question was duplicated to, and merged to.  Ideally, this is something that you should find when searching for the question before asking, or in the related questions as you ask, or in the related questions after you ask.  The target question has 11k views - other people have found it before and it is likely the accepted canonical answer for this problem.

You will also note a number of linked questions in the target duplicate as this has been asked several types with different wording.

When a question is merged, all the comments and answers from the source are merged into the target dup.  Comments that get too chatty or too rude, or are duplicating clarification, or are not appropriate in the target dup get removed as part of this process.

Additionally, any answers that are just reiterating what is said better are often removed as part of the merge.

That someone guessed your meaning and posted an answer isn't the best indication that your question was clear.  I personally have difficulty understanding exactly what you are after (trying to explain this to me, here will not be productive as there is nothing that I can do about it).

Having a question marked as a duplicate is not a *bad* thing.  It can help other people find the comprehensive answer in another question.

The best ways to contact an admin of this Stack Exchange site (it is not a forum) is to post on the persite meta that shows up under the drop down for stack exchange:

[image: how to find meta]

Or under the help drop down:

[image: how to find meta too]

Or sometimes, if you have sufficient rep to chat, in chat.

It is also important to remember that each stack exchange site is its own community.  The people active on Stack Overflow are different than the people active in Cooking or Photography or Pets or Bicycles or so on and so forth.  It is important to get a feel for the type of questions acceptable on the given Stack Exchange site and the questions that it allows.  Smaller SE communities (everything is *much* smaller than Stack Overflow) often have much more active moderation as its possible to watch and every single one of the 7.1 questions per day that Photography.SE gets compared to the 8.7K (1000x more) questions that Stack Overflow gets.  (see [all sites sorted by questions per day](http://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday))

Comment: Well said Michael, it's good general advice.

Answer (score 6):

I'll also take a stab at helping you understand what happened.  I am not a moderator on Photo, but I am a moderator on another SE site and have been around for a while.  MattDM behaved properly and is knowledgeable about what you were asking.

Your initial question was not clear exactly what you were asking due to grammatical problems, but the general question was still clear.  He initially marked it as "unclear what you were asking" because it was hard to follow.

Then, upon realizing that we have a question that covers file recovery (which is the same for either a corrupt card or a formatted one), your question was suggested as a duplicate of the question about how to do file recovery on a memory card.  The answers are in fact applicable to your situation, so it is a good match.

Then, after the community (it takes 5 people or one moderator agreeing that the question is a duplicate) agreed that the question was in fact a duplicate, a moderator (JoanneC) took care of merging the questions.  This moved the comments and existing answer from your question and placed them on the main question.  The question and comments on the answer weren't removed from the system, they were simply combined with the other question.

This is a good thing because it means that now a) there are more good answers to the general question on file recovery and b) there is now a second way for people to find that question by searching.  If they come across your question or the original question that has the answers, they will still get to a great set of answers for the problem.

As a community edited system, any member that is sufficiently involved earns the ability to edit posts or suggest closing or deleting a post.  Even users with low reputation on the site can suggest edits to a post and have the larger community approve their edit if it is an improvement.  This is helpful since it allows for a cleaner, easier to read site with higher quality questions and answers.

There is also a publicly available revision history available for anything the community does and most things moderators do, so even if someone makes an edit, your original version is never lost and you are able to revert edits made by other users if you don't think they are accurate to your intent.

Further, if your post is closed, you can edit the post to fix the problems and it will automatically be submitted to the community to vote if it should be re-opened.

The only thing really special in this case is that it was merged since there was a good answer.  A merge is a moderator only action and can't be reversed.  The lock is also placed automatically since the question has now effectively been rolled in to the main question and any answers or comments should happen on the main question.

I hope that helps with your understanding of how Stack Exchange works.  Please feel free to comment on this answer if you have any more questions and I'll try to get back to you on them.

Comment: Well said... I was fairly brief as I had to run to a meeting, but you guys covered the topic quite nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not particularly interested in having a kerfluffle over this, so I didn't respond right away, but after thinking for a bit, decided to make a generalized response that covers the root issue (without worrying about the details of this particular situation or any personal whatever).

So: please see
[Why is it important to provide apparently irrelevant details in a question?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4376/psa-why-is-it-important-to-provide-apparently-irrelevant-details-in-a-question/4377#4377)